# Quando usar WITH (NOLOCK)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
Select * 
from MinhaTabela with (NOLOCK)
```

Conheço colegas que sempre inserem a cláusula **With (NOLOCK)** em seus selects e conheço outros que pregam que o NOLOCK é má prática e que nunca deve ser usado.

Alguns alegam que com o **NOLOCK** temos mais performance, outros dizem que podem gerar erros lendos registros "sujos".

Os extremistas me assustam. Qual o ponto de equilíbrio? Ou seja, quando usar ou não usar **WITH (NOLOCK)** em minhas queries?

Answer (score 23):

Sua questão é muito interessante e é muito mais profunda do que a minha simples resposta e depende de fatores como: O que se pretende com a consulta, o SGBD em questão e tipo de leitura que você pretende.

Vamos definir dois conceitos antes:

leitura não confirmada ou suja "dirty read": ler dados de uma tabela que não foram confirmados por meio de commit. Ou seja, dados que estão temporariamente ali e podem sumir.

leitura confirmada "committed read": ler os dados que foram confirmados e que não sumirão no meio de uma transação naquele instante, por exemplo.

Quando utilizamos NOLOCK e o SGBD permite isso, serão devolvidos dados de leitura suja misturados com dados confirmados. Já, se você evitar o uso, serão apresentados somente os dados que foram confirmados com commit.

Portanto, um dado que não está "commitado" deve ser tratado como um dado que não existe para certas situações. São raros casos que você precisa de uma leitura de "dados não confirmados", temporários na tabela em questão, pois eles poderiam "sumir" dada alguma situação e você ficar com resultados inconsistentes no retorno.

Em resumo: Se o seu SGBD permitir, utilize NOLOCK quando deseja visualizar dados não confirmados e não quando deseja trabalhar somente com os dados que estão confirmados de fato.

Espero ter sido didático, explicando a diferença.
Um abraço

Answer (score 2):

"Nem tanto ao mar, nem tanto à terra"
(autor: desconhecido)

Vou dizer como eu uso o `With(NOLOCK)` e veja se faz sentido pra você?

1. Quando uso: verificações rápidas onde não há obrigação com a exatidão, não afeta o negócio.

> Exemplo: imagine um aplicativo de cartão de alimentação, tipo
> Alelo, SODEXO, onde você exibe para o usuário uma média de gastos
> diários, em tempo real, com base em suas compras. Este é um bom
> CANDIDATO a `With(NOLOCK)`

2. Quando não uso: onde a exatidão da informação é necessária pois afeta o negócio.

> continuando no mesmo aplicativo no exemplo anterior, precisamos exibir
> o saldo do cartão para o usuário. Neste caso NÃO RECOMENDO uso
> `With(NOLOCK)`.